# Publicar proyecto en Python 3.5 con heroku

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

Hola tengo un proyecto hecho con Python 3.5 y Django 1.10 y quisiera publicarlo en HEROKU pero veo que solo soporta Python 2.7, ¿alguien sabe si heroku soporta Python 3.5?

Answer (score 5):

Heroku soporta python hasta version 3.5.2 pero el valor de defecto es 2.7.12. Para especificar la version usa un archivo se llama `runtime.txt` y entra `python-3.5.2` en ese archivo.

Ponlo en la misma locacion que tiene `requirements.txt`.